# How to add Totals from Three Tables with SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

(Update 8/30: I revised my post with more details, hope this helps everyone.)
I've got three datasets in my report - each having file size details from three different sql servers.  Each dataset looks like this:

```
DATASET1
SERVERNAME    DATABASE    DATATYPE    FILESIZE
s1            db1         data        5,445
s1            db1         log         2,456
s1            db2         data        6,987
s1            db2         log         9,234

DATASET2
SERVERNAME    DATABASE    DATATYPE    FILESIZE
s2            db5         data         7,145
s2            db5         log          1,223
s2            db6         data        44,345
s2            db6         log          3,456

DATASET3
SERVERNAME    DATABASE    DATATYPE    FILESIZE
s3            dba         data        1,445
s3            dba         log           456
s3            dbb         data        4,556
s3            dbb         log         1,233
```

There are more rows in each dataset and each dataset has a different number of rows, because there are a different number of databases on each server.

I can easily create a tablix of totals for each dataset for each data type (data & log) grouping on data type and get totals that look something like this:

```
Server1         Server2         Server3
Data 34,445     Data 45,185     Data 98,334
Log  23,987     Log  12,993     Log 123,099
```

I want to create an overall total for all three datasets for each data type row.

```
Total
Data  177,964
Log   160,079
```

I know how to reference a specific dataset with SUM, but that is giving me the SUM for both rows.  I want a SUM for EACH row - total Data and total Log for all three servers.  I've tried using lookup as suggested but that's not giving me the total I want.  The code suggestion may work and I'm just not understanding it and implementing it correctly.

My sql is using sys.sysfiles, sys.database_files and sys.dm_os_volume_stats.  I tried adding the server name to those but I get a message "Remote table-valued function calls are not allowed."

Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: Well you are missing a key which combines one row from each dataset to one global row where alle the information from all three datasets is. Withouth the key you need a workaround. What you can do is, put a textbox in your report and reference it to your tablix of totals. Write in this textbox `=ReportItems!Server1DataTextboxName.Value + ReportItems!Server2DataTextboxName.Value + ReportItems!Server3DataTextboxName`. You get the names in the properties under name when you click on the values 34,445 / 45,185 / 98,334

Answer (score 0):

SUM is correct, just be sure to add whatever column holds the values for "Data" and "Log" to the group by.  To get it to display as you have above, add that field to "Row groups" and size to Values.  Leave server name out all together.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused.  I'm not sure this will add the totals from each dataset/tablix together.  I create a table and have to assign it to a dataset.  I have a column for data type (there are two rows, "Data" and "Log") and a column for Total Size, the resulting table displays two rows and a column header row.  In the Total Size expression I can say, sum(filesize,"server1") + sum(filesize,"server2") + sum(filesize,"server3") but that gives me the overall total for that dataset and I want the total for each row in each dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Lookup is your friend here.. you can simply insert a tablix.. assign the dataset to the first dataset and get the values from there.. add another column and then do a lookup to your other datasets something like this

For the Data row in your second columns.. you would have something like this :

```
=Lookup(Fields!Data.Value, Fields!Data.Value,  Fields!Data.Value, "Dataset2")
```

For the log row in your second columns.. you would have something like this :

```
   =Lookup(Fields!log.Value, Fields!log.Value,  Fields!log.Value, "Dataset2")
```

Add another column and repeat the above.. except it will be from Dataset3

Now you have all three columns coming from three different datasets.. you just need to insert another column and do a sum of the reportitems!

Then you can choose to hide the other three and show only the sum column or show all of them.. up to you

Comment: I haven't used Lookup before, sounds very promising!  Thanks, I'll let you know how it works out.

Comment: Either I'm not using it right or it's not working.  The only thing common between all three datasets is the data type, "Data" and "Log".  Each dataset contains detail info, so many "data" and "log" rows.  The Lookup is only getting the first "data" and "log" row it finds.  I want the sum of all "data" rows and all "log" rows from each dataset.  Sorry if I'm not explaining this well enough.  Thanks!

Comment: OK.. in that case.. use LookupSET rather than Lookup.. I just went with what you had in your question

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you have 2 Datasets with the following data:

```
Server1Data        Server1Number
34,445             1
12                 2

Server2Data        Server2Number
45,185             1
3                  2
5                  2
```

Your tablix is bound to Server1DatasetName. With **Lookup** you get the following result:

```
=Fields!Server1Data.Value 'Column1 expression
=Lookup(Fields!Server1Number.Value, Fields!Server2Number.Value, Fields!Server2Data.Value, "Server2DatasetName") 'Column2 expression

Column1    Column2
------------------
34,445     45,185
------------------
12         3      'The first match he finds
```

With **LookupSet** you get the following result:

```
=Fields!Server1Data.Value 'Column1 expression
=Join(LookupSet(Fields!Server1Number.Value, Fields!Server2Number.Value, Fields!Server2Data.Value, "Server2DatasetName"), VbCrlf)

Column1    Column2
------------------
34,445     45,185
------------------
12         3
           5      'Both matches seperated with VbCrlf in one row
------------------
```

But there is a third option. You put this **Function** in your report properties under **Code**.

```
Function SumLookup(ByVal items As Object()) As Decimal  

If items Is Nothing Then  
    Return Nothing  
End If  
Dim sum As Decimal = New Decimal()  
sum = 0  
For Each item As Object In items  
    sum += Convert.ToDecimal(item)  
Next  
return sum 

End Function
```

Now in your tablix:

```
=Fields!Server1Data.Value 'Column1 expression
=Code.SumLookup(LookupSet(Fields!Server1Number.Value, Fields!Server2Number.Value, Fields!Server2Data.Value, "Server2DatasetName")) 'Column2 expression

Column1    Column2
------------------
34,445     45,185
------------------
12         8     'Sum of both matches
```

Comment: That's quite interesting.  I'm not following that well, but I think I having been refreshed by sleep I didn't explain things well.  I'm going to revise my original post with more details - btw, this didn't work for me.